# Mapbox GL: Get Layer IDs

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a map with a few dozen layers, each with a unique ID. I have checkboxes to turn the layers on and off, for which I need a single array of all the layer IDs. I can't figure out how to loop through all of the map layers to capture the layer IDs. I tried using `map.getLayer()` but this returns the layer as an object, not the layer ID as a string. I want to loop through all of the map layers and push the layer ID strings to a new array. How do I do this?

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = "myaccesstoken";

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: "map", 
style: "mapbox://styles/mymapboxstyle",  
center: [-71.0664, 42.358],  
minZoom: 14 //  
}); 

map.on("style.load", function () {

map.addSource("contours", {
    type: "vector",
    url: "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2"
    });

map.addSource("hDistricts-2017", {
    "type": "vector",
    "url": "mapbox://mysource"
    });

map.addLayer({
    "id": "contours",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "contours",
    "source-layer": "contour",
    "layout": {
        "visibility": "none",
        "line-join": "round",
        "line-cap": "round"
        },
    "paint": {
        "line-color": "#877b59",
        "line-width": 1
        }
     });  

map.addLayer({
    "id": "Back Bay Architectural District",
    "source": "hDistricts-2017",
    "source-layer": "Boston_Landmarks_Commission_B-7q48wq",
    "type": "fill",
    "layout": {
        "visibility": "none"
        },
    "filter": ["==", "OBJECTID", 13], 
    "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#192E39",
        "fill-outline-color": "#000000",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
        }
    }); 

});

var layerIds = [];

function getIds() {

  //here I need to iterate through map layers to get id strings.
  //how do I do this???

 layerIds.push(    ); //then push those ids to new array.

 console.log(layerIds); //["contours", "Back Bay Architectural District"]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the layer ids when you add the layer; you can save them then:

```
function addLayer(map, options, layerIds) {
    map.addLayer(options);
    layerIds.push(options.id);
}

addLayer(map, {
    "id": "Back Bay Architectural District",
    "source": "hDistricts-2017",
    "source-layer": "Boston_Landmarks_Commission_B-7q48wq",
    "type": "fill",
    "layout": {
        "visibility": "none"
        },
    "filter": ["==", "OBJECTID", 13], 
    "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#192E39",
        "fill-outline-color": "#000000",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
        }
    },
    layerIds);
```

Answer (score 6):

If kielni answer isn't convenient because of unknown reason, use `map.getStyle().layers` to get an array of object layers then map it to get an array of string ids.

```
var layers = map.getStyle().layers;

var layerIds = layers.map(function (layer) {
    return layer.id;
});
```

Comment: Is it any way to get layer id from selected feature?